# Attempt to read property "permissions" on null in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to register a user to the system and assign the patient role by default.
The problem arises in the RegisterController controller.
In the create () method I write the following code:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $role = \App\Models\Role::where('slug', 'paciente')->first();
        $permissions = $role->permissions;

        $user->roles()->attach($role);
        $user->permissions()->sync($permissions);

        return $user;
    }
```

The error that laravel 8 throws is the following: **Attempt to read property "permissions" on null**

It is not recognizing as such the related permissions of the role saved in the $ permissions variable. What is the solution?

From already thank you very much!!!

Comment: It seems that you don't have the 'role' in your DB with field 'slug' = 'paciente'. That's why in this line
```
$role = \App\Models\Role::where('slug', 'paciente')->first();
```
$role is null

Comment: what roles do you have in your DB?

Comment: The role does not exist , perform a `dd($var)` on your roles variable

Comment: @AndrewMarkhai Thank you very much  your answer solved the problem. It turns out that I had previously done a migrate: fresh --seed and deleted the roles I had created. Greetings!

Comment: @Tomaguilera, no problem. If my comment helped, please, choose my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, it seems that you don't have the 'role' in your DB with field 'slug' = 'paciente'. That's why in this line

```
$role = \App\Models\Role::where('slug', 'paciente')->first();
```

$role is null. Check your role's table